# HttpExchange getRequestURI ends before the first ampersand "&"

Tags: java, parameters, uri, com.sun.net.httpserver

The original URI is (let's say):
`http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/mypath?parm1=1&parm2=he`

`getRequestURI` returns : `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/mypath?parm1=1`
It ignores the 2nd parameter.

If I replace the `&` by comma(s), it returns the full URI with all the parameters.

Have you experienced the same problem? Have you any solution?
Is it a way of reading the first GET header line via another method? (Using `HTTPServer`).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `HttpExchange.getRequestURI`, rather than `HttpServletRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

Sending the URI URLencoded, that is replacing special characters by percent uuencode code, resolves the problem.

Example: `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/mypath?parm1=1&parm2=he`

becomes: `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/mypath?parm1=1&parm2=he`

or even: `http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/mypath?parm1=1&parm2=he` (no need to encode the 1st part)

and `getRequestURI` returns all the parameters.